# jQuery animation interruption issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on angular program in which I have an image which I am animating by using jQuery **.animate()** property.Its working fine but the issue occur when I change the state using ui-router in middle of the animation.

It result in abrupt behaviour like even its url changes but the animation process still persist.I have tried **.stop()** , **.clearQueue()** and even **.finish()** property to end the animation before switching but nothing help me at all.

```js
app.controller('appCtrl',function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#character').animate({marginTop:"A1px",marginLeft:"B1px"},1000);
  },1000);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#character').animate({marginTop:"A2px",marginLeft:"B2px"},1000);
  },3000);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#character').animate({marginTop:"A3px",marginLeft:"B3px"},1000);
  },5000);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#character').animate({marginTop:"A4px",marginLeft:"B4px"},1000);
  },7000);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#character').animate({marginTop:"A5px",marginLeft:"B5px"},1000);
  },9000);
});
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="">
    <img src="character.png" id="character" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <input type="button" name="name" value="BACK" ui-sref="backpage">
    <input type="button" name="name" value="NEXT" ui-sref="nextpage">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.stop()` is often not enough. Have you tried using `.stop(true, true)`? Also, when posting a code snippet,et make sure that when you run it, it actually works. Right now I just get a bunch of JS errors.

Comment: yep even that's not working

Comment: use `ngAnimate` for animations.

Comment: oh ok , but cant we rectify the above issue as I am thinking of using that as last resort

Comment: if you use jquery that will happen. Also, post a plunker or fiddle with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oi1hBG8aVc5KWYyZWI6d?p=preview).

Use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) and on controller destroy remove the timeout .

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $timeout.cancel(timer);
});
```

Better practice do never merge [jQuery with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngAnimate` instead of jQuery's `.animate()` property.

Check [here](http://www.nganimate.org/) for illustrations and examples.

For the above. try this

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(#character)).animate({marginTop:"A1px",marginLeft:"B1px"},1000);
```

instead of

```
$('#character').animate({marginTop:"A1px",marginLeft:"B1px"},1000);
```

Comment: I am still getting confused can any one help me to write the equivalent code like Sibi Raj said and also I want to resolve the issue which I stated above.Thnx in advance

Comment: @AmitRSingh. Create a simple plunk with your problem. I will chek

Comment: check the above link ,and try to switch states between first page and second without letting second stage to complete its animation